# get max value for each related model with eloquent in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 2 model:

```php
class Message extends Eloquent {

    public function conversation(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Conversation', 'conversationId');
    }


    public function sender(){
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'senderId')->select('id', 'userName');
    }


    public function receiver(){
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'receiverId')->select('id', 'userName');
    }
}

class DeskConversation extends Eloquent {

}
```

What I want is to take all the last messages of each conversation (those included in a given array)... in other words I would like to take some conversations and, for each of them, only the last message that was exchanged.

I'm able to get all the messages for all the given conversation with this:

```php
return Message::whereHas('conversation', function($query) use ($convIds) {
    $query->whereIn('id', $convIds);
})->with('sender')->with('receiver')->orderBy('conversationId')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
```

where `$convIds` is an array of ids.

How to take, for each conversation, only the last message?

p.s. both models have timestamps fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
/**
 * Conversation has one latest Message
 *
 * @return Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
 */
public function latestMessage()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Message')->latest();
}
```

Then just:

```
$conversations = Conversation::with('latestMessage')->get();
// then each latest message can be accessed:
$conversation->latestMessage;
$conversations->first()->latestMessage;
```

Comment: I've another problem on this query... how if i would like to sort the ENTIRE collection (not just the related) by the message id? If I use the join it returns all the messages and not just the last for each conversation...

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Show the query you need or at least describe it precisely.

Comment: Found [this](http://laravel.io/forum/02-21-2014-order-and-paginate-a-collection-by-a-releted-field-using-eloquent) (you are ubiquitous...) but finally I solved in this way: `->sortByDesc('lastMessage.id');`