# laravel - eloquent - get sum of related model specific column

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

assuming that I have the table

> orders

with fields

> id, userId, amount, description

and the table

> user

with various fields

how if I wand to get all the users (with all its fields) and also the sum of the "amount" column  of the orders related to that user?

assuming that I have:

> user:{id:15,firstName:jim,lastName:morrison,gender:male}

and

> order:{id:1,userId:15,amount:10,description:"order xxx"},
>
> order:{id:3,userId:15,amount:40,description:"order yyy"}

I would like to receive:

> user:{id:15,firstName:jim,lastName:morrison,gender:male,orderAmount:50}

Of course I would like to avoid the foreach statement.

I've setted this on my user model

```
public function userOrder (){
    return $this->hasMany('Order', 'userId');
}
```

And I've tryed this:

```
return $this->hasMany('Order', 'userId')->sum('amount');
```

without any luck...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some thaughts and hopefully an answer to your question:

I would rename the user table to users to stick to laravel conventions.
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#basic-usage

I would name the method in the User model orders

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Order', 'userId');
}
```

To query a user, his orders and sum afterwards his orders amount values:

```
$userdata = User::with( 'orders' )->where( 'userId', 15 )->first();
$sum = $userdata[ 'orders' ]->sum( 'amount' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was very vague in defining my tables...of course it is called "users" and my model is called "User", but I am afraid yours is not the solution I'm looking for... Take a look at [this]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25655388/get-max-value-for-each-related-model-with-eloquent-in-laravel  and see how Jarek Tkaczyk solved my problem with "latest()" function...i looking for something like that

Comment: ah oh ... I don´t see that in your question but hey, I´m happy you found your solution :-)

Comment: Forgive me, my English is bad and I have trouble explaining the issue... the link I posted is related to another question where what I wanted to point out is how with that solution I was able to take only the last message among those related, without use a foreach. The problem persists :(

Comment: Just found out you can use the sum function even in loop in blade templates. So if you have many orders you can use @foreach($users as $user)   {{$user->orders->sum('amount')}} @endforeach